# Is it possible to create a 'link to a folder' in a SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create a shortcut to a folder in a different document library in a document library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the following pattern:

```
http://[server]/[site]/[ListName]/[Folder]/[SubFolder]
```

To place a shortcut to a document library:

1. Upload it as *.url file. However, by default, this file type is not allowed.
2. Go to you Document Library settings > Advanced Settings > Allow management of content types. Add the "Link to document" content type to a document library and paste the link

Comment: How do you work out what [ListName] and [Folder] etc have to be?  The URL in my browser for the folder has all sorts of "other stuff" in it:  [server]/TeamSite/VHA%20MRTM%20Document%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FTeamSite%2FVHA%20MRTM%20Document%20Library%2FOffers%2FVHA%2FLocation%20Services%20Mediator&FolderCTID=0x012000472F18C20FA2D841A168829871757219&View=%7BC8AB31AA-99A5-4A49-A8A8-5636874CE0C9%7D

Comment: @GreenAsJade Add the `[server]/` string to the `TeamSite%2FVHA%20MRTM%20Document%20Library%2FOffers%2FVHA%2FLocation%20Servic‌​es%20Mediator` string. Or to state it more generically, Add the `[server]/` string (which may be formatted as `http://server/`) to the string following `?RootFolder=%2F`, up to the first ampersand (&). Note that the `%2F` string represents the slash character (/), so including the slash after the server name **and** `%2F` would double the slash after the server name.

Comment: For what it's worth, on SharePoint Online, any time I tried to upload a shortcut to a document in another SharePoint library somewhere, it just uploaded the document itself. I had to open the site in IE11, then select "Open in File Explorer", and then paste the shortcut (the .url file) into the document library while in Explorer view.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't change the permissions on the sharepoint i'm using but got a round it by uploading .url files with the drag and drop multiple files uploader.

Using the normal upload didn't work because they are intepreted by the file open dialog when you try to open them singly so it just tries to open the target not the .url file.

.url files can be made by saving a favourite with internet exploiter.