# How to link to a folder in document library from sharepoint list item?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, wss

**Background:**

I have an items on the sharepoint list. I also have a corresponding folder in a document library that contains documents about this item. I want to be able to get to this folder straight from the item properties. I have tried to create a lookup column containing folder ID, but that doesn't help cause folder is not a type and it just doesn't work. Other solution would be to create link column but if I will create it staticly - after creating alternative mapping (and getting to the page from the internet for example) it won't work. (so solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042771/is-it-possible-to-create-a-link-to-a-folder-in-a-sharepoint-document-library) won't work for me).

I want to create this link from sharepoint workflow. I have a custom action that can return any info about the folder I want (ID, URL etc).

**Question:**

How to link from sharepoint list item to a folder in document library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally try to avoid using folders. In numerous instance I've found they arn't worth the trouble and the key with SharePoint is not to reproduce the typical folder hierarchy that you'll find on a file system. Break away from that mess and do it the SharePoint way and put the documents straight into the list and use views and metadata to break up the documents into manageable groupings.

That said, a folder is it's own content type and it works perfectly well in a lookup column. You have to reference the list item id for the folder of course. I just created a folder in a standard document library, added a lookup column to a custom list and successfully referenced the folder in a new item. When I click the folder lookup then I get taken to the folder item, which contains an "Open" link that takes me to the documents contained within the folder.

Comment: Wow.. I've just checked and it worked. My problem was I used property that does not exist for a folder as a link name (and then I was trying to troubleshoot a workflow inspite of the list). Thanks for checking it out and pointing the problem! About lists - I will have over 300 elements on the base lists so my workflow would need to create 300 separate lists. I'm a little afraid to go this way.

Comment: Actually I have found a bug elsewhere. Workflow was run with System account privileges and folder was created also with system account. So it's probably a permission issue.

Comment: 300 elements (documents in the list). I take it you mean that you associate a workflow to run on creation and then import 300 documents into the library in which case every document will get an instance of the workflow starting. An insane suggestion not because of performance, but for the poor user that'll get 300 tasks. Perhaps you want to associate the workflow after the import. You'll never want all items to have a workflow at teh same time will you?

Comment: I agree. The workflow is for the future systems (each item on the list coresponds to new client - more clients more items). I didn't think about the way how I will import data from the old system yet. But it's excel spreadsheet so just copy&paste should be ok :)

Comment: The only problem with putting all of the documents in one folder comes when you have duplicate file names.  Say I have a custom list named 'Projects'.  I also have a document library named 'Project Documents'.  'Project Documents' has a lookup column to 'Projects' so that each document is tied to a specific project.    I can use views to see only the documents for a single project.  But what if I have project A with "Contract.pdf" and now I need to save another "Contract.pdf" for project B?  Without saving to a separate folder B's copy will overwrite A's on save.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search and found a free feature for linking easily.
Watch the demo video on codeplex.

http://easylinkdocs.codeplex.com/

Yes - really good - BUT the original question was for a way to link to documents from a LIST and the tool you have linked to DOES NOT do this. Looks pretty neat for linking between Libraries though!

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's working for me. From the top: I have a document library with folders. In my case each folder represents a unique event and each folder has 0 or more documents. The document library is named "Event Documents."

I also have a custom list name named "Events." The Event form has an "Event" lookup field that points to the Event Documents "Title" field. As such, the drop down menu on the Event form shows me all the folders in the document library.

When an Event form is saved, a sharepoint designer workflow fires. The workflow set's the field "Event Folder" to "Event Documents:URL Path" where "ID" is equal to Current Item "Event."

Bottom line, I've found no way to cobble together the URL of a parent folder except via a SPD workflow. The workflow can grab the URL (and other attributes) of the folder when it has the ID of the folder in hand.

Answer (score 0):

Dude i got a simple solution Out Of the box ; i discovered it a while ago :

the solution is to make a Column named title ; Then create a new folder ; then press action>edit with spread sheet > then write the title for that folder 
this phase is now finished then in the lookup colomn you can refere it to the title colomn you will find the folder is there

thanks to me